# The DataContext object and assigning its properties

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

The short story is that I would like to be able to assign an IEnumerable to my Context.Customers property (this being table imported from SQL of type System.Data.Linq.Table; Customer being an entity type).

Now the first thing you might wonder is 'why would you do this?' Yes, ordinarily there are better ways to do this, but I am not operating under ordinary circumstances. A limitation on my project means I do not have access to the 'web' part of the project. As a result, I'm going about this using a WCF service hosted in IIS. This service holds the DataContext object and makes the calls to the database, and it communicates with the Silverlight application.

The Silverlight application calls GetCustomersAsynch and then waits for the completed event, at which point it can use a collection of Customer entities. My problem is about **submitting** those changes. I can send the altered collection back to the WCF service, but the 'Customers' property of the DataContext object is read only so I can't just assign one to the other. I can't just write them over one for one either, because there might have been a new entry added (or, potentially, new entries). What I want is for the DataContext's Customers property to be updated with the passed collection, and then I will call Submit on the DataContext to submit the changes to the database.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using WCF RIA Services, WCF Data Services, or just plain WCF Services?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. `DataContext` is supposedly the `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` class, isn't it? But if so, how can you use it in Silverlight code if LINQ to SQL is not supported in Silverlight? You shouldn't event be able to add a reference to the corresponding assembly.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had mentioned that one. The DataContext instance is in the WCF service. I access the information in it via calls to my WCF service from the Silverlight application. When I pass new data to the service, I need it to update the DataContext object before I can tell it to submit its changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static DataContext in your WCF servic, though it is usually discouraged. Then send the whole object from Silverlight to the WCF service method. Inside the WCF service method, call staticCtx.UpdateObject(customer); and SubmitChanges(). If you loaded the customer object with the same staticCtx, then UpdateObject will change the state to changed and submitChanges will send it through the engine to convert it to update SQL. There can be several side-effects of a static context, so beware.

Another option, is to use WCF Data Services or WCF RIA Services (L2S works) and Entity Framework. Then you can actually call SubmitChanges on the client and use LINQ to query from the client.

Here is [one of many RIA Services](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-RIA-Services-Part-3-Updating-Data.aspx) articles that are available and one for [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361.aspx). There are a lot of considerations on how to the make the choice between the two.