# Writing to the DataContext

Tags: c#, datacontext

I have a function. This function takes an `IEnumerable<Customer>` (`Customer` being an entity). What the function needs to do is tell the `DataContext` (which has a collection of `Customers` as a property) that its `Customers` property needs to be overwritten with this passed in `IEnumerable<Customer>`. I can't use assignment because `DomainContext.Customers` cannot be assigned to, as it is read only.

I guess it's not clear what I'm asking, so I suppose I should say... how do I do that? So we have DataContext.Customers (of type System.Data.Linq.Table) which wants to be replaced with a System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable. I can't just assign the latter to the former because DataContext's properties are read only. But there must be a way.

**Edit**: here's an image:

[image]

**Further edit**: Yes, this image does not feature a collection of the type 'Customer' but rather 'Connection'. It doesn't matter though, they are both created from tables within the linked SQL database. So there is a dc.Connections, a dc.Customers, a dc.Media and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking or how this relates to WCF...

Comment: possible duplicate of [The DataContext object and assigning its properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359199/the-datacontext-object-and-assigning-its-properties) You should update that question if you have not yet found your answer.

Comment: Sorry Terry, I thought the DataContext object fell under WCF. What does it fall under if not that?

Answer (score 0):

Your collection IsReadonly. This can happen when you have an Interface in you viewstate, or an other place which serializes the collection. If it is deserialized it is readonly because it does not have a implementation of the interface its functions.

Comment: amazing two pears replied to same question, my last name means the same in Sardinian language :)))

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to `UPDATE` all `Customer` entities in the context having same `ID` of the entities in your IEnumerable, you can use an approach like in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4212581/559144

Answer (score 0):

Is it not `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`??

**Answer version** *(for those struggling to see that this rhetorical question was a proposed answer):*

It's `DataContext.SubmitChanges()`

Comment: Before I can submit the changes, I need to make sure the DataContext has the changes, which is what I'm doing. As for why I'm doing it this way, it's a not particularly interesting story.

Comment: Haha I'm sure it isn't. Have you got a bit of code we can look at? I don't know a great deal mate but might be able to help if you give us an example.

Comment: Okay, I added an image to the main question which contains code.

Comment: It does provide an answer. It was just worded in a way that maybe made it look more appropriate as a comment - everybody else who read it seemed to see past that though. Edited

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, Collections should be readonly most of the time.

You just have to clear the collection, then add every new item using a foreach:

```
private void SetItems(IEnumerable<MyObject> _NewItems)
{
    myCollection.Clear();
    foreach (MyObject newItem in _NewItems)
    {
        myCollection.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does look like what I'm looking for, except the type in the collections is System.Data.Linq.Table<Customer> and there are no 'clear' or 'remove' options so far as I can see.

Comment: You can use myTable.RemoveAll(myTable) in your case i believe.

Comment: I altered the main question and added an image. As you can see, there is nothing under 'R' except 'IsReadOnly' and 'Reverse<>'.

Comment: What is the type of dc.Connections? there is no "Connections" property in System.Data.Linq.Table<Customer>, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx

Comment: I beg your pardon, in the example I use the entity 'Collections' rather than 'Customers'. It's just a table that has been imported from the database. Other tables include 'Customers' and 'Users'.